# Sub query with multiple result

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with Sql Server, I have written one query.when i'm executing that query getting following error.

Error:

> > "Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> >         Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

```
SELECT b.booking_id,b.booking_ref,b.destination,b.room_format,b.checkin,b.checkout,b.booking_status,b.currency,b.rooms,b.booking_date,

b.adults,b.childs,b.seniors,b.youth,b.child2,b.booking_type,

pb.amount_charged,pb.original_total_cost 'total_amount',b.special_request,b.cancelled_date,b.emergency_contact,b.emergency_email,

(SELECT TOP 2 CAST(isbreakfast AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + room_desc FROM tbl_hotel_room_booking WHERE pb.product_booking_id = product_booking_id) 'room_desc',

tba.traveller_address1,tba.traveller_address2,tba.traveller_city,

tba.traveller_state,tba.traveller_country,tba.traveller_zip_code,

th.transaction_amount,th.reversal_amount,th.branch_id,th.agent_id,th.transaction_type,

pb.product_booking_id,pb.product_status,pb.provider_confirmation_code,pb.booking_source,pb.product_name,pb.product_type,pb.product_id,

tft.ticket,

(SELECT TOP 1 as_of_date + '_' + hotel_penalty FROM tbl_hotel_room_cancellation WHERE booking_id='0BCE1ABC-EA42-4030-A9F1-CA8D176825C0') 'as_of_date',

tpd.adult_price,tpd.cost_currency,tpd.sell_currency,tpd.booking_fee,tpd.taxes,tpd.exchange_rate,tpd.subagency_markup_val,

tpd.charged_amount,tpd.child_price,tpd.senior_price,tpd.youth_price, tpd.actual_price,(ISNULL(tpd.markup_total,0) + ISNULL(tpd.subagency_markup_val,0)) 'markup_total', tpd.markup_total 'agency_markup'

FROM tbl_booking b 

INNER JOIN tbl_product_booking pb ON b.booking_id = pb.booking_id

LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction_history th ON b.booking_ref = th.reference_number

LEFT JOIN tbl_traveller_billing_address tba ON b.booking_id = tba.booking_id

LEFT JOIN tbl_purchasedproduct_details tpd ON b.booking_id = tpd.booking_id

LEFT JOIN tbl_flight_tickets tft ON b.booking_id = tft.booking_id

WHERE b.booking_id = '0BCE1ABC-EA42-4030-A9F1-CA8D176825C0'

AND (th.transaction_type IS NULL OR LOWER(th.transaction_type) = 'booking' OR LOWER(th.transaction_type) = 'creditcardbooking' OR Lower(th.transaction_type) = 'manualbooking')
```

Finally i know why i'm getting this error..I'm trying to return multiple result from sub query..

```
(SELECT TOP 2 CAST(isbreakfast AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + room_desc FROM tbl_hotel_room_booking WHERE pb.product_booking_id = product_booking_id) 'room_desc',
```

can any one help how can i return multiple result here.

Comment: if i have two rooms with same product id ..then i need to return two rooms description ..

Comment: Lots of things you need to work on 1. sub queries in your select clause are not recommended 2. a top clause without a order by is nearly meaningless

Answer (score 0):

If you basically left join your query with that table and set filter for top 2 records i think you will get what you want.

```
SELECT  
b.booking_id,
b.booking_ref,
b.destination,
b.room_format,
b.checkin,
b.checkout,
b.booking_status,
b.currency,
b.rooms,
b.booking_date,
b.adults,
b.childs,
b.seniors,
b.youth,
b.child2,
b.booking_type,
pb.amount_charged,
pb.original_total_cost 'total_amount',
b.special_request,
b.cancelled_date,
b.emergency_contact,
b.emergency_email,
CAST(brb.isbreakfast AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + brb.room_desc  AS 'room_desc'
tba.traveller_address1,
tba.traveller_address2,
tba.traveller_city,                                             
tba.traveller_state,
tba.traveller_country,
tba.traveller_zip_code,     
th.transaction_amount,
th.reversal_amount,
th.branch_id,
th.agent_id,
th.transaction_type,        
pb.product_booking_id,
pb.product_status,
pb.provider_confirmation_code,
pb.booking_source,
pb.product_name,
pb.product_type,
pb.product_id,
tft.ticket
(SELECT TOP 1 as_of_date + '_' + hotel_penalty FROM tbl_hotel_room_cancellation WHERE booking_id='0BCE1ABC-EA42-4030-A9F1-CA8D176825C0') 'as_of_date',

tpd.adult_price,tpd.cost_currency,tpd.sell_currency,tpd.booking_fee,tpd.taxes,tpd.exchange_rate,tpd.subagency_markup_val,

tpd.charged_amount,tpd.child_price,tpd.senior_price,tpd.youth_price, tpd.actual_price,(ISNULL(tpd.markup_total,0) + ISNULL(tpd.subagency_markup_val,0)) 'markup_total', tpd.markup_total 'agency_markup'

FROM tbl_booking b 

INNER JOIN tbl_product_booking pb ON b.booking_id = pb.booking_id

LEFT JOIN  tbl_hotel_room_booking brb ON pb.product_booking_id = brb.product_booking_id

LEFT JOIN tbl_transaction_history th ON b.booking_ref = th.reference_number

LEFT JOIN tbl_traveller_billing_address tba ON b.booking_id = tba.booking_id

LEFT JOIN tbl_purchasedproduct_details tpd ON b.booking_id = tpd.booking_id

LEFT JOIN tbl_flight_tickets tft ON b.booking_id = tft.booking_id

    WHERE b.booking_id = '0BCE1ABC-EA42-4030-A9F1-CA8D176825C0'
        AND brb.isbreakfast IN (Select Top 2 IsBreakfast 
                                                FROM tbl_hotel_room_booking)
        AND (th.transaction_type IS NULL 
             OR LOWER(th.transaction_type) = 'booking' 
             OR LOWER(th.transaction_type) = 'creditcardbooking' OR Lower(th.transaction_type) = 'manualbooking')
```

Comment: not working getting errors ..Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 52
The multi-part identifier "b.booking_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
The multi-part identifier "b.booking_ref" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
The multi-part identifier "b.booking_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
The multi-part identifier "b.booking_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
The multi-part identifier "b.booking_id" could not be bound.

Comment: sorry not like this i want . I want *room_desc* with comma separate ..i have used like this now getting but how can i use these lines in above query                ` DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + COALESCE (room_desc, CAST(isbreakfast AS VARCHAR(10))) FROM tbl_hotel_room_booking where product_booking_id = 74097 select @names`

Comment: You can not both select and set your variable. You can erase the select variables and put the your new declare vraiable(names) It should look like
Select
@Names = COALESCE (room_desc, CAST(isbreakfast AS VARCHAR(10)))
and you should use yout where statement in the end of query;
WHERE b.booking_id = '0BCE1ABC-EA42-4030-A9F1-CA8D176825C0'
AND tbl_hotel_room_booking where product_booking_id = 74097
AND brb.isbreakfast...